# Using Select Command With a DDL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm having some problems with my code. Basically I want a DDL that has a list of values from a table sorted by the primary key. When an item is selected and a button is clicked, a Grid View shows the rest of the information about the respective record. I'll post the code I have now. For some reason, nothing appears in the DDL at all and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            grv1.DataSource = srcCSC;
            grv1.DataBind();
        }
    }


    void btn1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSourceSelectArguments objSelectArg = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        DataView objView = (DataView)srcCSC.Select(objSelectArg);

        srcCSC.Select(objSelectArg);

        //rebind
        grv1.DataSource = srcCSC;
        grv1.DataBind();
    }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            City:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" DataSourceID="srcCSC" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="City"  /><br />


            <asp:SqlDataSource
                ID="srcCSC"
                runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xyz1%>"
                SelectCommand="Select City, CompanyName, ContactName, Relationship From CustomerSupplierCity Where City=@City">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCity" Name="City" />
            </SelectParameters>
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
     <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btn1" Text="Select" runat="server"
                OnClick="btn1_click" />

            <asp:GridView ID="grv1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="City,CompanyName,Relationship" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```